# Index out of bound exception (Stacks)

Tags: java, generics, stack

i'm currently working through generic classes and stacks. I've created a class with an arrayList and create methods for push, peek and pop.

Whenever I run the driver though I get an index of of bounds exception and i'm confused to why. Any help would be great:

```
GenericStack class



public class GenericStack <T> {

  public ArrayList<T> stack = new ArrayList<T>();

  private int top = 0; 

  public int size () {return top; };

  public void push (T element){

    stack.add(element);

    top++;    
  }

  public T pop() {

    if (top == -1) {
      return null;   //means stack is empty
    }

    T val = stack.get(top);

    stack.remove(top);

     top--;
     return val;
  }

  public T peek(){
    if (top == -1){
      return null;
    }

    T val = stack.get(top);

    return val;

  }
}
```

and my GenericDriver class

```
public class GenericDriver extends GenericStack {

public static void main (String [] args){

GenericStack<String> strings = new GenericStack<String>(); 


                    strings.push ( "hi");
                    strings.push ("how are you?");
                    strings.push ("Hi again");
                    strings.push ("One more");


    if (strings.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println("Stack is empty.");
    } else { 
      System.out.println("Stack contains " + strings.size() + " items.");
    {   
      System.out.println("top value: (using pop)  " + strings.pop()); 

      System.out.println("Stack now contains: " + strings.size() + " items");

      System.out.println("The new top value, using peek:  " + strings.peek());
    }
  }
```

If anyone could tell me why i'm getting this exception it'll be brilliant

Comment: At which line do you encounter the exception?

Comment: As a sidenote: There is `LinkedList` which also offers a Stack API.

Comment: Line 27 on the driver when the pop method is called.

Comment: is it trying to do a pop() on an empty array?

Comment: Try remove (top-1), because if your list has a length of 'top',  the List.get(top) will return an index out of bound exception.

Comment: _Please_ take a few seconds to indent your code before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stack looks like this:

```
"One more"
"Hi again"
"how are you?"
"hi"
```

Now `top` is **4**.

When you do `pop`, you're trying to get the element at index `4` in the *ArrayList*, but arrays are zero-based in Java, there is no element 4, the elements are in the range `[0-3]` You should initialize `top` to -1 instead of 0 at the beginning, so when you'll try to get the "top" element, you won't get `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 1):

Decrement `top` previously to pop the element from the list.

```
top--;
T val = stack.get(top);
stack.remove(top);
```

Because top has the number of the elements, since the array is zero-based the index is always one less than the number of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you start `top` as 0. When adding one item to the stack, you increment top. Now your top value is 1. But the index which you should use in `pop()` should be 0, not 1, because the first index of an `ArrayList` starts at 0.

Thus you should initialize your `top` as -1 instead of 0. (which is what you also check for later to signal an empty stack).

Answer (score 0):

```
On first push operation GenericStack.push("java") increases to "1". Then if we
```

perform GenericStack.pop(), we are trying to fetch from index '1' for which 
object is not initialized. Below code changes should work:-

```
private int top = -1;   
public int size () {   
return top;   
}   
public void push (T element){   
top++;   
stack.add(element);   
}
```